# "Would" used to tone down a strong and controversial statement

Tags: modal-verbs, usage

I have read in https://www.butte.edu/departments/cas/tipsheets/grammar/would.html that would is used  **to tone down strong, controversial statements**. The website defines it as follows:

> To tone down strong, controversial statements- not recommended in formal essays:
>
> *I would have to say that you're acting a bit immature.*
>
> Here, **would** has a similar meaning to **do**, but less emphatic.

I don't quite understand how we can use **would** to "Tone down strong, controversial statements". How the sentence with **would have to** tone downs strong or make controversial statement in above sentence?

Could you please make these clear to me?

Comment: See this definition: **would** modal verb (OPINION)  used to express an opinion in a polite way without being forceful http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would

Answer (score 2):

In such phrases, **would** might be paraphrased as a kind of conditional: "If asked, I would say that ...".

The modal distances the speaker from the statement.

> You're acting recklessly.
>
> I would say you're acting recklessly.

The second shows a slight reluctance to make a simple straightforward declaration, which translates to a faint whiff of deference or politeness.